# Disable Win FW - via WinRS?

Tags: windows

Security practitioner working on MCSA, trying to see what I could do with WinRS from remote, namely disabling the firewall.

```
winrs -r:1.1.1.6 netsh
firewall
offline
sh mode
```

Returns that the firewall is offline, yet when I'm sitting on 1.1.1.6 and sh the mode it shows as online.  Sure enough if I exit the WinRS session, and re-enter netsh, it shows as online.

Wondering what feature is preventing this from being disabled, or if it's just a (good) limitation of WinRS.  Thanks in advance.

(Final note on lab setup - both machines are in trustedhosts, and have REMOTEADMIN enabled in the firewall to begin with)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of options depending on your version of Windows.

- UAC will prevent you from controlling the firewall with netsh if you're not using an elevated session.
- netsh firewall is deprecated in recent versions of Windows and you should be using netsh advfirewall firewall instead.

Comment: UAC is disabled in registry, so that shouldn't be impacting it.  I know netsh is deprecated, however, when sitting on the box, entering the command works just fine, and executing via winRM and cmd.exe is exactly the same as being on the box.  I'll try with advfirewall in the meantime unless you get any other ideas.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: can you confirm disabling the firewall via winRM is possible and not a limitation of winRM's abilities?